# How to export the results of a stored procedure directly to a MS Excel file?

Tags: sql, excel, ado

I found a way to extract the contents of a MS Sql table directly (faster) to excel. But I do not know how to do this with a stored procedure that requires parameters. Is it possible to extract, directly, to an Excel File the results of a stored procedure? I know how to do it indirectly (using a data table) but it is too slow. Thank you very much.

PS: This is the method I was using to do some tests. It works with a table, but what I need is to extract the result of a stored procedure:

```
    Private Sub SqlToExcelTest2(ByVal excelFilePath As String, _
                            ByVal nonExistingSheetName As String, _
                            ByVal sqlServer As String, _
                            ByVal sqlDatabase As String, _
                            ByVal sqlUserName As String, _
                            ByVal sqlPassword As String, _
                            ByVal sqlTable As String)

    Const excelConnStrTemplate As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2"";"

    Dim connStr As String = String.Format(excelConnStrTemplate, _
                                          excelFilePath)

    Const adoQueryTemplate As String = "SELECT * INTO {0} FROM [odbc;Driver={{SQL Server}};" & _
    "Server={1};Database={2};UID={3};PWD={4}].[{5}] "

    Dim query As String = String.Format(adoQueryTemplate, _
    nonExistingSheetName, _
    sqlServer, _
    sqlDatabase, _
    sqlUserName, _
    sqlPassword, _
    sqlTable)

    Using oleConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr), oleCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, oleConn)
        oleConn.Open()
        oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        oleConn.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: If you only do this occasionally for testing, can you use the Management Studio functionality for exporting to Excel? Set the query output to go to Excel, then run the sproc in a query window.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have Excel right now to check, but you might try:

1. Start recording a new macro
2. on a new worksheet select menu Data->Import, and something like "data source"
3. choose your table/view (I am not sure if stored procedure is also supported)
4. setup all the credentials etc.
5. follow the rest of the steps...
6. stop recording macro

and take a look at the generated VBA code.

If you always run the same query (or few different ones), then creating few of such *data sources* with the *auto-refresh on startup* could be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Is Python an option for you?

A contrived stored procedure that takes a parameter and returns a result set:

```
create procedure usp_Temp @howmany tinyint
as
set nocount on

create table #tmp (ID int identity, Letter char(1), String varchar(50))

declare @i tinyint
set @i = 0

while @i < @howmany
begin
  insert into #tmp (Letter, String) values('X', 'The quick brown fox...')
  set @i = @i + 1
end

select * from #tmp
set nocount off
```

In Python, you could do something like this:

```
import dbi
import odbc
import csv

conn_str = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Uid=MyLogin;Pwd=MyPwd'
conn = odbc.odbc(conn_str)
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute('exec usp_temp @howmany = 15')
results = curs.fetchall()

curs.close()
conn.close()

writer = csv.writer(open('tmp.csv', 'wb'), delimiter = ',',
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for result in results: writer.writerow(result)
```

Excel should be able to open up that CSV file without a problem.